# Set value of a cell based on the text color of another cell on the same row

Tags: excel

I have received an Excel file where some rows on a sheet have a red text color. These are the rows that should be flagged as "to be removed". So I have added a new column on the table called "Status".

On this column, if the text color of another column (say "email") on the same row is red, I would like to have a value of 1 and otherwise 0.

How should I create the formula or rule for these cells?

Answer (score 0):

I will normally create a function to get the colour index.

`
Function text_colour(x As Range)

```
text_colour = x.Font.ColorIndex
```

End Function
`

[image]

Comment: Sorry! I'm quite bad at Excel. Where do you create and save this function?

Comment: Under Developer tab > Visual Basic. if you do not have developer tab follow this link, https://www.addintools.com/documents/excel/how-to-add-developer-tab.html

Comment: Alternatively, Alt + F11, then create new module